# Play: Automating test data setup

Tags: testing, playframework, automation, sbt

I have a playframework project that has reached beta/user testing.
For this testing we require test data to exist in the environment
I am looking for a way to automate this via scripts.
The best way will be via call's to the API passing the correctly shaped data based on the models in the project (thus dependant on the project not external).
Are there any existing SBT plugins that I could utilise that would be able to create the appropriate JSON and pass it to the API to setup the environment

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a plugin for this? I think what you want to do is to have a set of Json, then call the end-points and see what is the response from the back-end. In case of "setting up" based on a call that has a Json, you could use `FakeRequest` in your tests:

```
 val application = newGuiceApplicationBuilder().build()
 val response = route(application, FakeRequest(POST, "/end-point")).get 
 contentAsString(response) must include("where is Json")
```

In your test you can also test the response from the back-end and the Json you are feeding it:

1. Create a set of Json using `Writes`, based on a case class you are using in the back-end. You could also purposely create an invalid Json as well, that misses a field for example; or has an invalid structure.
2. Use Table driven testing and sending `FakeRequest` with the body/header containing your Json; and then checking it against the expected results.

I'm on the move, when I get home, I can write an example code here.

Comment: I dont want to use tests as they are run seperately, what i have done instead is to create a second Main and then use Sbt runMain. But this has created a mess as far as deployment (it deploys the Main instead of the play project)